# In its earliest usage, did the notation "5 x 3" mean "five groups of three" or "five, placed into each of three groups"?

Tags: math-history

In today's time, if I take a look at what language we use to read out "5 x 3", it could be read out as "five-times three" (that is: three, five-times, as in five groups of three), or "five multiplied by three" (that is, five, placed into each of three groups").

My main question is:

- In its earliest usage, did the notation "5 x 3" mean "five groups of three", or instead "five, placed into each of three groups"?

My more minor questions are:

- Historically, when did the vocabulary of "times" (as in "five times three") first start to be used, to describe multiplication (as in "5 x 3"), and in what contexts (eg educational contexts? financial contexts? personal correspondence that mathematicians would write to each other? etc) ? (Implicit in this question, is an understanding that the equivalent of "times" might have first been used in a language different than English).
- Similarly, historically, when did the language of "multiplied by" (as in "five multiplied by three") appear, and in what contexts?

Comment: I suspect this would be better asked on the English StackExchange, along with the origin of the usage: "Take 5, and times it by 3". The only thing mathematics has to contribute to this discussion is, "Well, multiplication is commutative, so it's fine?"

Comment: You say "*but very rarely '3x' or '2x' to communicate the same idea*"  I have the opposite impression.  I see both.  "*the 'five times' seems to be the most interesting thing*"  That is your personal opinion and not rooted in much fact.  That is a matter of language more than mathematics... words appearing first in some languages do impart a somewhat greater weight when it comes to importance, but when it comes to math such things are usually done devoid of emotion.

Comment: You seem to be getting at the nuanced difference between the multiplicand and the multiplier... [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication).  In the end, the order in which multiplicands and multipliers are written is irrelevant, situational, and ultimately up to personal preference.  Even the whole notion of "multiplication is repeated addition" is merely a naive teaching tool which does not tell the whole story of what multiplication really is and it fails to work as a metaphor for things like $\pi\times \sqrt{2}$.  It is best to grow out of using that interpretation.

Comment: My personal take on this (which may-or-may-not comport with terminological history) is that the phrase "five times three" is better written as "five-times three", where "five-times" is part of the sequence "once, twice, thrice, four-times, five-times, ..."; thus, the phrase indicates *five copies of three*. On the other hand, "five multiplied by three" means *three copies of five*. And then there's the somewhat neutral "product of five and three". The notation "$5\times 3$" can be read in any of these ways. (But note: "five, timesed-by three" is an abomination. :)

Comment: Funny, I hear 2x or 3x multipliers and have never heard of an x2 multiplier.

Comment: BTW, the dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a good/better place for this question.

Comment: @Blue aha! i didn't know that existed. i wonder how difficult it would be to migrate this question (or if it would even be appropriate to do so)

Comment: @JMoravitz interestingly, the Wikipedia article you suggested has a paragraph that suggests an answer about "What does 3x4" mean, and the English words we use today to verbalize "3x4" in speech *today* (even if it doesn't say anything about its historical usage). The paragraph says:  `For example, 4 multiplied by 3, often written as "3x4" and spoken as "3 times 4", can be calculated by adding 3 copies of 4 together:`

Comment: @silph: I believe a moderator could decide whether migration is appropriate, and perform the migration, as necessary. I think you can get a mod's attention by flagging your question, or you could post to [Meta.Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Blue thanks very much for the idea

Comment: The appropriate site for this question is being discussed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35211/11619) in meta.

Comment: For a non-integer factor, we usually write $5\pi$ and not $\pi 5$.  So I conclude that the left-hand factor is the multiplier, and the right-hand factor is the multiplicand.  Linguistically (from Latin), multiplier = that which multiplies, and multiplicand = that which is to be multiplied.

Comment: Maybe you have to consider very ancient times... see e.g. Bartel van Der Waerden, [Science Awakening (1961, original ed 1950)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Science_Awakening_I/HK3vCAAAQBAJ), page 18 for multilication table in Egyptian [Rhind Mathematical Papyrus (it dates to around 1550 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhind_Mathematical_Papyrus#Book_I_%E2%80%93_Arithmetic_and_Algebra)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea the answers to your historical linguistic questions, which are better asked in other forums, but will provide a mathematical answer since you posted here. :)

As indicated in the comments, because ordinary whole number multiplication is *commutative*, the number $m\times n$ can be interpreted equivalently as
$$m\times n=\underbrace{m+\cdots+m}_{n\text{ terms}}$$
or as
$$m\times n=\underbrace{n+\cdots+n}_{m\text{ terms}}$$

There is a similar dual interpretation of whole number division. If $n$ divides $m$, then the quotient $m\div n$ can be interpreted equivalently as either

- $m\div n$ = the number of groups if $m$ objects are partitioned into equal groups of $n$ objects
- $m\div n$ = the number of objects in each group if $m$ objects are partitioned into $n$ equal groups

The first interpretation is sometimes called the **measurement interpretation**, while the second is called the **partitive interpretation**.

In contexts where multiplication is not commutative, there is no such equivalence. For example with ordinal multiplication, $\alpha\cdot\beta$ means (intuitively) ``$\alpha$ repeated $\beta$ times'', so
$$2\cdot\omega=\underbrace{2+2+\cdots}_{\omega\text{ terms}}=\omega$$
while
$$\omega\cdot 2=\underbrace{\omega+\omega}_{2\text{ terms}}>\omega$$